# How to send User-scoped custom dimensions in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to send User-scoped custom dimensions in GA4 via JS. I have defined `test_custom_dimension` as a user custom dimension in GA4 admin console. Next, I am loading GA4 in the frontend as follows:

```
        <script
            async
            src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXX"
        ></script>
        <script>
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag() {
                dataLayer.push(arguments);
            }
            gtag('js', new Date());
            gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXX', {
                send_page_view: false,
            });
        </script>
```

Now, I've tried a lot of things, currently using `config`:

```
window.gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXX', {
        user_id: userId,
        test_custom_dimension: 'true',
    })
```

As well as `set`, **but the data does not show up anywhere in GA4**. I've done quite a lot of searches on Google, and everyone says something different ("use config", "use set", "don't use set it's bugged", ...), yet I can't get anything to work.

The only thing I haven't tried yet is setting the user custom dimension via Google Tag Manager. Is this the only way to do it? Is it not possible using JS itself?